# Problem with CORS when using cookies in apollo-server-rexpress and create-react-app

Tags: typescript, cors, create-react-app, react-apollo, apollo-server

I am using apollo-server-express in the backend and react in the frontend. I want to use cookies for authentication so I set up my server like in the code below, which is the result of multiple tutorials and workarounds. Still when I am sending any request from the frontend, I am getting a CORS error.
I also tried adding

> "proxy": "http://localhost:4000/",

to the package.json file of the react app.

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4000/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```js
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import {
  ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer,
  ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault,
} from "apollo-server-core";
import { context } from "./context";
import { schema } from "./schema";
import "dotenv/config";
import express from "express";
import http from "http";
import session from "express-session";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const startApolloServer = async () => {
  const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

  const app = express();
  app.use(
    session({
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 1,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        secure: true,
      },
      genid: () => uuidv4(),
      secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET as string,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
    })
  );
  app.set("trust proxy", true); //process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production");
  app.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://studio.apollographql.com");
  app.set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

  const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
  const plugins = [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })];

  process.env.__dev__ &&
    plugins.push(ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault());

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    //context: ({ req, res }: any) => ({ req, res }),
    context,
    plugins,
    introspection: !isProduction,
  });

  await server.start();

  server.applyMiddleware({
    app,
    cors: {
      origin: ["https://studio.apollographql.com"],
      credentials: true,
    },
  });

  await new Promise<void>((resolve) =>
    httpServer.listen({ port: process.env.PORT }, resolve)
  );
  console.log(
    ` Server ready at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`
  );
};

startApolloServer();
```

That's my setup in the frontend:

> const httpLink = createHttpLink({
> uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
> credentials: 'include',
> });

I am looking forward to your answers! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I had to add http://localhost:3000 to my cors settings:

```
server.applyMiddleware({
   app,
   cors: {
     origin: ["https://studio.apollographql.com", "http://localhost:3000"],
     credentials: true,
   },
});
```

I am still wondering why this was not added in all the tutorials?!